# ¿Cómo cambio de idioma Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Acabo de descargar e instalar la ultima versión de Android Studio, pero toda la interfaz me aparece en ingles, existe alguna forma de cambiarla a español, porque estuve buscando y no encuentro como.

Comment: En Xamarin [según este enlace](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-studio/customizing-ide/) es: `Preferences > Environment > Visual Style` y seleccione el idioma = ¿has intentado algo para cambiar el idioma del IDE?

Comment: Si @Ma  he revisado de pie a cabeza el IDE en preferencias, pero no encuentro tal opción, muchas cosas cambiaron de lugar con respecto a la versión anterior

Comment: Ricardo, puedes [edit] la pregunta agregando mas detalles de la versión, posibles logs de eventos = intento ayudarte buscando alguna información :)

Comment: a un no existe en version español

Comment: QUIEN ME PUEDE COLABORAR? COMO SE CAMBIA EL IDIOMA EN ANDROID STUDIO

Comment: La interfaz sera en ingles predeterminado ya que aun no hay una version en español

Answer (score 2):

Se puede realizar pero no para todos los textos de la IDE.

Ve a el directorio donde se tiene instalado `Android Studio` y accede a `\plugins\properties\lib`, por ejemplo:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\properties\lib
```

ahí se encontrará el archivo :

```
resources_en.jar
```

si extraes este archivo puedes modificar el archivo llamado `PropertiesBundle.properties`, puedes cambiar los textos a idioma español:

```
duplicate.property.key.error.message=Duplicate property key
rename.prefix.based.property.key.error.message=Could not rename property key ''{1}'' based on prefix ''{0}'' by name ''{2}'', change prefix first
properties.files.file.type.description=Properties
remove.property.intention.text=Remove property
rename.bundle.enter.new.resource.bundle.base.name.prompt.text=Enter new resource bundle base name
rename.bundle.enter.new.resource.bundle.section.name.prompt.text=Enter new resource bundle section name
rename.resource.bundle.dialog.title=Rename Resource Bundle
rename.resource.bundle.section.dialog.title=Rename Resource Bundle Section
properties.files.inspection.group.display.name=Properties Files
unused.property.inspection.display.name=Unused Property
searching.for.property.key.progress.text=Searching for {0}
unused.property.problem.descriptor.name=Unused property
remove.property.quick.fix.name=Remove Property
no.property.selected.panel.label=<html><body><center>Please select property name on the left to edit its values</body></html>
...
...
...
```

Cabe aclarar que no todos los textos se encuentran aquí.